# How can I setup a network connection with Puppet?

Tags: networking, puppet

I need to set up a network between three computers using Puppet:

- Node A connects to Node B through a firewall
- Node B connects to Node A through a firewall and connects to Node C
- Node C connects to Node B

How can this be done?  I have never set up a network before, save unwrapping a WiFi router.

---

> Puppet is a tool that is used to automate processes and configurations
> typically once you have a process or configuration identified. It
> seems here that you aren't sure what you wish to do. It would help to
> know if this is Windows or Linux (or Mac ). Do you have the physical
> cabling completed? Are these computers all on the same subnet? Do you
> have an IP addressing scheme in mind? It seems to me that you are not
> providing nearly enough information.
>
> ---Gregg Leventhal

The (virtual) machines live on a VM server (vSphere), and they are all (cloned) RHEL 5.9.  I have the configuration 'identified', I'm just not exactly sure what I mean what I mean when I say *PostGIS is installed* or *B connects to C*.  So, in that sense, I have not identified the configuration, but I have rather determined what needs to happen.  I have a total lack of process.

I'd say the following:

```
192.168.<dev-no>.<node-no>
         dev-no=0 => master
                  node-no => 1/A, 2/B, 3/C
```

Nodes A, B, and C are going to be duplicated for each developer.  So, as for the ideal network setup, all nodes A will live on one network while all nodes B and C will live on another.

I apologize for my ignorance; I'm only an intern and I think I've been tasked a bit beyond my ability.  (But, that's the only way you learn anything really *new*.)

Comment: I was not sure where to post this; since Puppet is also a language, SO also seemed to be a good fit, but Puppet also is a pretty niche tool (where that niche is a good portion of SU).

Answer (score 3):

Puppet is a tool that is used to automate processes and configurations typically once you have a process or configuration identified.  It seems here that you aren't sure what you wish to do.  It would help to know if this is Windows or Linux (or Mac ).  Do you have the physical cabling completed?  Are these computers all on the same subnet?  Do you have an IP addressing scheme in mind?  It seems to me that you are not providing nearly enough information.

In Red Hat linux, you typically would define the network settings of an individual computer within the file `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` (assuming you wish to define the first network interface, eth0 ).  You would use puppet typically to automate redundant tasks or to enforce that specific configuration files maintain the correct settings and revert to the proper state even after being modified.  Typically a puppet master server would check for changes on a file and revert them every 30 minutes.  This is an odd task for puppet as assigning IP addresses to a few machines is a one-off task.

If you must do it in Puppet, you could look into using an erb template for the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` file.
The issue is that each machine must have a unique IP address, like 192.168.1.2, 192.168.1.3, 192.168.1.4, and so on.  I believe, with all due respect, that this task may involve too many factors that are foreign to you.  You can also use puppet to have certain services listen for changes to related files.  In this case, you would want the `/etc/init.d/network` service to reload after you have modificed the ifcfg-eth0 file, adding an IPADDR=192.168.1.X entry, where X is a unique number.

Comment: Gregg, I updated my question, and it includes this concern as a qualification.  Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: No disrespect taken *whatsoever*.  If the network stuff really is a one-off task, I will probably execute it as such.  I'll ask my supervisor about that when he returns tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you wouldn't use Puppet to configure a system's networking -- you certainly *CAN* [as Gregg points out in his answer](https://serverfault.com/a/513179/32986), but it's a chicken-and-egg scenario:

1. Puppet operates over the network, therefore Puppet requires the machine to be connected to the network.
2. You want to use Puppet to configure the network, which presumably means the machine is NOT on the network.
3. Puppet operates over the network (goto 1)

---

Since IP configuration is usually a one-time thing, and  I have to do it manually at least once to break the chicken-and-egg cycle above, it's not typically something I manage with Puppet (or any other configuration management tool) -- I keep records of which machines have what address (separate from configuration management), manually configure the systems as they're built, and thereafter the network settings should never be changed.

This means I need to manually log in to each machine if I ever change my IP addressing scheme, but that should be infrequent enough that it's not a major inconvenience worth my time to implement management of the network configuration.
If you expect to be changing the IP address of machines regularly managing them with Puppet might make sense for your environment (but I'd argue if you're renumbering machines frequently you're probably Doing It Wrong).

Comment: My use case would be: the VMs are already connected to the Puppetmaster, and just need specific connections with each other, so I think that precludes any chicken-and-egg scenario (I *think*).  I probably *am* doing it wrong, but I realized I don't have any experience from which to look at things (and I'm trying to [fix that](http://serverfault.com/questions/513177)).

Comment: The machines can't be connected to the puppetmaster until they have a valid, functioning network configuration. Machines cannot have a valid, functioning network configuration until the network is configured...

Comment: I suppose my own blissful ignorance is getting in the way of understanding the ramifications of what I'm asking. :-)  I'll trust that this truly is the scenario, and the question is answered as 'unanswerable'.

Comment: @Sean It's not unanswerable, it's been answered two different ways. The answer (at least *my* answer) is "There's no reason to manage this with puppet because it just creates extra work"

Comment: But if there is no way to use Puppet to configure network connections per its own need for the network, then how is this question supposed to be answerable?  Sure, it could work *in theory*, but nobody would be able to test it.

Comment: @Sean you can't use puppet to configure a machine that doesn't have a network connection. No network = client can't talk to the puppetmaster.

Comment: @NathanC, I hope I've already made it *clear* that I'm still learning about the very nature of networks.

Comment: You can run puppet manifests without being connected to the puppet master.  Sure, it's pretty useless in this case, but you do not NEED to be on a network to run a .pp file that would configure the network via the puppet agent, in theory.  You would use puppet apply to do so.

Comment: Also, I was working in my last job, with the Senior Ops guy to come up with a bootstrapped kickstart image that would ultimately assign a temporary address, install puppet and sync with puppet master, and then pull a unique IP from a static pool.  Technically, we were doing exactly what is being discussed here, which is assigning a static IP to a machine that was being configured with puppet.  I thought it was a heavy handed process, but the techops guy was very skilled and I am sure he got something fairly decent working, or maybe he scrapped the idea :)